# php class_exits not working as expected

Tags: php

I am trying to check if class exists and it returns false but if i check manually, it works successfully. Why is it so.

```
<?php

$controller_file = 'app/controllers/user.php';
$controller = 'User';

/**
 * Check if controller file exists
 */
if(!file_exists($controller_file)  ){
    throw new Exception(" Missing controller file");
}
require_once($controller_file);

/**
 * Check if controller and method exists
 */
if(class_exists($controller, false)){
    throw new Exception("Invalid Controller"); //this error thrown
}

$user = new User(); // these work 
var_dump($controller);
?>
```

Comment: Two different things.. You are checking for existence of file in the first check and in the second check, you are checking if the class has been defined or not.

Comment: I see problem in your second check. Shouldn't that also include ! (not)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working, you forgot a `!`, it should actually be:

```
if (!class_exists($controller, false)){
    throw new Exception("Invalid Controller"); //this error thrown
}
```

Your current code reads "if class User exists, throw an exception". Pretty sure you want "If class User doesn't exist, throw an exception".

Comment: is there anything similar to set_include_path() for file_exists and all others. I wish to set base path for all operations

Comment: You want [chdir](http://ca3.php.net/chdir) but you can only change to one main directory which affects all relative paths